# NSPopUpButton not updating selectItem

Tags: macos, cocoa, xcode6, nspopupbutton

I have a `NSPopUpButton` where I'm preselecting item in the menu and is been selected but is *not* showing as selected. Here is my code:

```
[self.categoryMenu selectItemWithTitle:@"cineRush"];
```

Here is how is showing:

[image]

But here is how show if I click on the `NSPopUpButton`:

[image]

But it show `"cineRush"` as selected item.

Any of you knows why this is happening or how can this fix?

Comment: I'm not sure, but you may need to call `synchronizeTitleAndSelectedItem`.

Comment: Thank you this work perfectly